# How to generate word document based on two lists in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, reporting, sharepoint-2013

I know that it is possible to generate a word document from a list, but what if I need data in my word document from two lists?

I can create a linked data source which combines the two lists, but I have not seen any example on using the linked data source to create a word report. The list relationship is one-to-many, so the first list has header information, while the other has item information.

Can someone point me in the right direction for this? I'd like to do this without any libraries such as OpenXML etc.

Thanks,
gixen

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused regarding "I'd like to do this without any libraries such as OpenXML etc."

If you really need to create solution without any library, then, maybe, [WordML](http://wcornwill.wordpress.com/2007/01/17/document-generation-using-wordml-word-2003/) could help you. Or you could deal with docx files content manualy (it is bunch of zipped files). However this really would be time consuming task. If you need to create document I would insist on using OpenXML SDK.

If "without any library" means you would like to avoid writing code you could try our [product](http://www.sharepointdrive.com/).

Comment: I mean I'd like to avoid writing custom code that will have to be maintained. 

Your product seems to do the job, so I'll have a look at that.

A solution that can be done in standard Sharepoint 2013 is preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating it in MS Excel?

You can have a VLOOKUP to get the one-to-many relationship addressed:

LIST ONE:
dog
cat

COMBINED LISTS ONE AND TWO:

dog fido

dog king

cat mittens

Comment: Good suggestion, but the contents of the lists are long texts, and must look like an actual document.